# Crash using Here Lite Maps when returning to a screen with MapViewLite from background

Tags: android, crash, here-api

The crash happens when user re-enters a screen with the MapViewLite component after sufficient delay (or with "Don't keep activities" dev option set). It doesn't depend on anything in the calling code - happens even in the bare "HelloMapLite" sample project provided with the SDK.
Here Lite version used: 4.4.0.2.2340 (but I've first discovered it on version 4.3.3.0.2052)

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
    at android.os.Parcel.readByteArray(Parcel.java:2249)
    at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState$1.createFromParcel(Unknown Source:3)
    at com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite$SavedState$1.createFromParcel(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2790)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2684)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:3134)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2367)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2741)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3053)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
    at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1010)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.restoreState(FragmentStateManager.java:236)
```

Auto-decompiled code of MapViewLite:

```
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable var1 = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    MapRenderer var2;
    if ((var2 = this.mNativeRenderer) != null) {
        MapViewLite var10000 = this;
        byte[] var3 = var2.saveViewState();
        byte[] var4 = var10000.getMapScene().saveLayersState();
        return new MapViewLite.SavedState(var1, var3, var4);
    } else {
        return var1;
    }
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable var1) {
    if (var1 instanceof MapViewLite.SavedState && this.mNativeRenderer != null) {
        MapViewLite var10000 = this;
        MapViewLite var10001 = this;
        MapViewLite.SavedState var2;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState((var2 = (MapViewLite.SavedState)var1).getSuperState());
        var10001.mNativeRenderer.restoreViewState(var2.getViewState());
        var10000.getMapScene().restoreLayersState(var2.getLayersState());
    } else {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(var1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally this error comes when the reading from the Parser is not the same order as the class constructor fields are defined. Mind checking any warnings that you may be getting. Can you please share some sample code that would help in debugging.

Comment: It crashes during restoring of your class, MapViewLite, using your sample code, the HelloMapLite sample project from the SDK bundle downloaded from Here's page.

Comment: There are more than 1 instance of MapViewLite. only one MapViewLite instance can be created at a time.  please refer Add the Map View section in https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.4.0.2/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html

Comment: I think it's an answer to my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048997/mapview-by-here-crashes-when-calling-mapview-oncreate-in-a-single-activity-archi

Yes, I've read that documentation before. However this requirement is wrong, because it is inconsistent with the Fragment lifecycle. Can you show me an example how to get from one Fragment with a Map View to another Fragment with a Map View without getting a crash? I don't think it is possible, because onDestroyView callback in the old fragment will be called AFTER the onViewCreated callback in the new fragment.

Comment: Can you tell on which device / Android version this happens?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S9, Android 9 - but a tester reported it to me also on 2 other devices. Just turn on "Don't keep activities" in Dev Options, leave a screen with a map view and go back to it - crashes every time.
Frankly, this bug makes Here maps unusable for us, so unless this is fixed in a reasonably short period of time, I will have to recommend another mapping solution to the customer.

Comment: Indeed, this points to a bug in the SDK. Thanks for the additional input. Good news: I just heard from HERE that a fix for this is ready and will be included in the next release (scheduled to go live next week).

Comment: Thank you. Since we are in dev stage, we don't have a paid plan yet, so I assume that SO is the only support available to us - unless there is another way to report an SDK bug to Here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems fixed in version 4.4.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this bug was fixed with version 4.4.3.0. For me it is no longer reproducible and according to the *release notes* this bug has been fixed with **HERE SDK for Android (Lite Edition), Version 4.4.3.0.**: "Fixed a crash in `MapViewLite` when an app is coming back to an `Activity` from background.".

Comment: Sounds great - is it accessible to the public though? From my project page on developer.here.com I can still only see the 4.4.2.0 version of all Android SDKs.
Also no docs for the new version, as you can see (in the dropdown) here: 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.4.2.0/dev_guide/index.html