# MapView by Here crashes when calling mapView.onCreate in a single Activity architecture

Tags: android, crash, here-api

I'm using a single-activity architecture, with Fragments as screen, and using the Navigation component. In the first fragment, I initialize the map in onViewCreated and destroy it in onDestroyView.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    loadMapScene()
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    mapView?.onDestroy()
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

From this fragment, user can navigate to another fragment with a map, which also calls mapView.onCreate in its onViewCreated. However, using the newest (4.4.0.2.2340) Here Maps Lite library it crashes, because:

MapViewLite.class

```
private static boolean mInstanceActivated;

public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle var1) {
    if (!mInstanceActivated) { 
        //various initializations
        mInstanceActivated = true;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Only one MapViewLite instance can be created at a time");
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    this.mNativeRenderer.dispose();
    this.mNativeRenderer = null;
     // setting to nulls
    mInstanceActivated = false;
}
```

In the normal Fragment lifecycle, onViewCreated of the fragment navigated to happens before even onPause (not to mention onDestroyView) of the fragment navigated from. That means the second mapView.onCreate is called before the first mapView.onDestroy() and thus its RuntimeException is thrown. Interestingly, it didn't crash in the 4.3.3.0.2052 version (to which I reverted for now).
Could you please make the Here Lite MapView usable in a single Activity architecture?

Comment: Android's fragment lifecycle is different from an activity lifecycle, but you should be able to properly destroy the 1st mapView instance before the second one is created. The trick would be to do this before you navigate to the new fragment that wants to create a second instance.

Comment: That would require calling mapView.onDestroy() in every navigation out of this Fragment, including ones from side menu. Yet, it is possible, but requires a lot of maintenance and in general is an awful practice. 
For now I'm just using the older version of the Here Maps library (4.3.3.0.2052) which, for some reason, doesn't crash in this scenario.

Comment: It's strange that the older version works for this scenario. Maybe just by accident ... Another idea is to switch to the Explore or Navigate Editions of the HERE SDK for Android: Both Editions allow multiple map view instances, even within the same layout.

Comment: I tried the Explore edition. It's true it doesn't crash, however the map in second is black, with warning:

View config is empty. No map content will be displayed until valid config is provided.

And after that an error:

E/harp-sdk: [ERROR] harp-sdk - Failed to attach RenderTarget to View.

The same fragment displays ok if it is the first to display, without a transition from another fragment with a map.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to call mapView.getMapScene().loadScene() on the 2nd map view? If not, this could be a regression and might be worth to open a separate question (or contact HERE to get the bug filed). At least, it worked for me when I tried this a few weeks ago. When you call loadScene(), do you get a MapError?

Comment: Fair point - I'll create a new ticket.
Answering your questions - I definitely call loadScene and get no errors - like I said, if this fragment is started as the first one, everything works ok. It's only the mapView.onCreate from 2nd fragment being called before mapView.onDestroy from the first one that causes problems.